# Different password for Roundcube and external IMAP/SMTP

Tags: mysql, email, postfix, dovecot, roundcube

Is it possible to have the Roundcube password, and the password that's used for IMAP and SMTP connections (such as when using a mail app), be different?
I would like to do this because I've set up 2 factor auth via a plugin on round cube, but this is essentially useless for the moment. But since the Roundcube password is the same as the IMAP/SMTP password, then someone with the password could access the emails anyway through a 3rd party mail app and bypass Roundcube.
Are there any instructions available as to how this could be done?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Roundcube isn't anything more than webface for imap/smtp client.

So no, without saving imap password on the system and then automatically login when authenticated in another way, you can't choose different passwords.

Answer (score 1):

`Dovecot` allows the shared folders so you can access the same storage with the same messages from two different IMAP accounts. You can refer to the next manual explaining exact configuration:

https://wiki.dovecot.org/SharedMailboxes/Shared

Also if you have an access to the host serving your `dovecot` you can simply softlink the "main" imap userdir for the secondary account(s) having a separate IMAP credentials.

Comment: All of those require access to mailserver and creation of multiple connected mailboxes which somehow isn't the same as one account with multiple passwords.

Comment: All the toolset is listed in the tags so I've supposed that this is fully controlled setup.